# SparkML LogisticRegression vs Sklearn's: Different coefficients and intercepts

Tags: scikit-learn, pyspark

I may be missing some initialization parameters or something like that.

I created an LR in `pyspark` and then one using `Scikit`. I trained then using the same data. When I got the resulting models I compared their parameters. The `Coefficients` were very different. The `intercepts` in `pyspark` turned out to be a single number and that is still very different from that of sklearn.

The predictions are the same in terms of labels however the probability values are different

- pyspark==2.3.2
- scikit-learn==0.20.2

**pyspark LR creation:**

```
data = self.spark.read.format("libsvm").load(input_path)
lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=10, tol=0.0001)
model = lr.fit(data)
predicted = model.transform(data)
```

**sklearn creation:**

```
sk_model = linear_model.LogisticRegression()
sk_model.fit(np_x, np_y)
sk_expected = [sk_model.predict(np_x), sk_model.predict_proba(np_x)]
```

**Data conversion from spark to numpy:**

```
self.spark.udf.register("sparseToArray", lambda x: x.toArray().tolist(),
                       ArrayType(elementType=FloatType(), containsNull=False))
    np_y = data.select("label").toPandas().label.values.astype(numpy.float32)
    np_x = data.selectExpr("sparseToArray(features) as features").toPandas().features.apply(pandas.Series).values.astype(numpy.float32)
```

Comment: As far as coefficients are concerned, you may try increasing `maxIter` in your pyspark code and see if the two from pyspark and sklearn converge.

Comment: Thanks @SergeyBushmanov
While increasing the iterations from 10 to 100 resulted in some changes I cannot say that there is any convergence. Some start to fall apart more while some get closer. Increasing the iterations from 100 to 1000 resulted in no changes to the coefficients (as far as eyeballing goes)

Comment: corrected the statement about intercepts. sklearn gives me one intercept like it should. The value is close but different beyond a 0.1 tolerance